# Is there a proof of the spherical law of sines?

Tags: spherical-trigonometry

I know that the spherical law of sines is $\frac{\sin A}{\sin a}=\frac{\sin B}{\sin b}=\frac{\sin C}{\sin c}$ but how does one prove this rule?

Comment: No, it is an unsolved conjecture ... </sarcasm>

Comment: @Henry There better be, otherwise is not a "law" but at best "A good shot" or a "What are the odd this time it won't work?" guess

Comment: You can see here: http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic246919.files/March-07.pdf

Comment: Thanks @EmilioNovati, that's perfect

Answer (score 5):

Choose a coordinate system so that the three vertices of the spherical triangle is located at 
$$(1,0,0),\quad (\cos a,\sin a,0)\quad\text{ and }\quad(\cos b, \sin b\cos C, \sin b\sin C)$$
The volume of the tetrahedron formed from these 3 vertices and the origin is  $\frac16 \sin a\sin b\sin C$. Since this volume is invariant under cyclic relabeling of the sides and angles, we have
$$\sin a\sin b\sin C = \sin b\sin c\sin A = \sin c \sin a \sin B
\implies\frac{\sin A}{\sin a} = \frac{\sin B}{\sin b} = \frac{\sin C}{\sin c}$$

Comment: Hi, but the above has no known geometrical meaning.